What is the earliest recorded devotional hymn to Lord Vishnu?
Some sources (such as Wikipedia) state that the Shri Suktam is the earliest recorded devotional hymn that reveres Shri Lakshmi.
Seeing this made me wonder: What is the earliest recorded devotional hymn that reveres Lord Vishnu?
The Narayana Suktam is said to be chanted together with Shri Suktam as part of five Vaishnava suktams, and seems to have been composed during a similar period of history — and before the Purusha Suktam that is also included among the five.
Does that make the Narayana Suktam the earliest recorded hymn to Lord Vishnu?

any answer will be subject to historical opinion.

Sources exist, which have been dated (at least to within a range, and subject to the widely accepted limitations of dating historical documents).
